# Binary search for a string in a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search

I have a list of permutations of a string, and a list full of words from a lexicon. I want to for each permutation find out if it's in the list of words. I tried a while loop and just brute-forced through and that gave me a bunch of words from the wordlist. But when I tried this binary search:

```
def binärSökning(word, wordList):
    first = 0
    last = len(wordList) - 1
    found = False
    while first <= last and not found:
        middle = (first + last)//2
        if wordList[middle] == word:
            found = True
        else:
            if word < wordList[middle]:
                last = middle - 1
            else:
                first = middle + 1
    return found
```

I got nothing in return, just an empty list (Just false, if it returns true it adds the word to another list). Can anyone please tell me why it's not returning true when it hits a good word?

Edit:
What's calling the function is just a for-loop:

```
foundWords = set()

for word in listOfWords:
    if binärSökning(word, NewWordList):
        foundWords.add(word)

return foundWords
```

Where the NewWordList is the a narrower list of possible words it could be, nothing wrong with it, since it worked when I tried brute force.

What I would like as a result is when ever the searching function returns true, the for-loop adds that word to a set that is then presented to the user once the program finishes.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you have, and what you would like to get ? E.g. some dummy data so we can reproduce your code

Comment: I've updated with a bit more explanation.

Comment: This is the first - and hopefully last - time I've seen diaereses in a function name. I'm surprised it even works! For good order, maybe stick to non-accented letters :).

Comment: Will try to remember that in the future, but that's not the problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It was working fine for me. The following was my code:

```
def binrSkning(word, wordList):
    first = 0
    last = len(wordList) - 1
    found = False
    while first <= last and not found:
        middle = (first + last)//2
        if wordList[middle] == word:
            found = True
        else:
            if word < wordList[middle]:
                last = middle - 1
            else:
                first = middle + 1
    return found
```

The following was my output

```
>>> binrSkning('hi', ['hello', 'hi', 'how'])
True
>>> binrSkning('tim', ['hello', 'hi', 'how'])
False
```

The following worked fine for me:

```
>>> NewWordList = ['hello', 'hi', 'how']
>>> listOfWords = ['hi', 'how', 'bye']
>>> foundWords = set()
>>> for word in listOfWords:
        if binrSkning(word, NewWordList):
            foundWords.add(word)

>>> foundWords
set(['how', 'hi'])
```

Comment: Works for me to, but when I plug it in the real thing it doesn't do anything but tell me False. I change nothing yet this doesn't work.

Comment: Could you share what you have plugged in?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of words, it is as simple as making a single if statement as follows:

```
def bomrSkning(word, wordList):
    found = False
    if word in wordList:
        found = True
    return found
```

Comment: Yeah, but the list of words is about 20000 some words so wouldn't that take some time to go through?

Comment: Do you have the words ordered in some way in order to find them more quickly? If not, I can not figure out a faster method

Comment: The list of words is alphabeticly organized if that helps, the list of words doesn't matter what order they come in as they go in one at the time